# Get request parameters not appending properly in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have running the JMeter for performance testing,

For GET request the parameters are not appending properly

[Get Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnCSQ.png)

[Request's response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3IRO.png)

I don't know what i am missing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to have protocol, host and port in "Path" field of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, you should use the relevant inputs for this.

[image]

Moreover, having the full URL in the "Path" section might cause malfunction of i.e. [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager), [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager), etc.

If you're uncertain about how to properly build the HTTP Request you can just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension.](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium)